# Passing quotes in Process.Start arguments in C#

Tags: c#

How to run this statement in Process Arguments in C#.

This works all fine however I'm worried that if one of the two args for mklink has a space that this wont work correctly. So I added "" around both parameters. Executing this line no longer worked and when I wrote "" instead it still didn't work.

Here is My code

```cs
////Run EXTERNAL APP AS AN ADMIN

string d = "test1234";

SecureString pass = new SecureString();

foreach (char ch in d)
{
    pass.AppendChar(ch);
}
string filepath= @"C:\Program Files (x86)\LalTechnologies\LT_Service\LT_Administration.exe";
string arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", filepath);

string filep = arguments;
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        //CreateNoWindow = true,
        //WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        Password = pass,
        UserName = "test",
        Domain = "soft",
        FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe",

        Arguments = $"Start-Process -FilePath "+arguments+$" -Verb RunAs",
       
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    }
};

//*Set your output and error(asynchronous) handlers
   
process.Start();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // do something with line
}
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\LalTechnologies\LT_Service\LT_Administration.exe" -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string literal, just prefix the string with an `@` and use double quotes were you want a quote to be.

```
string quotes = @"this ""string"" has quotes"; // this "string" has quotes
```

to use it with a interpolated string just use both `$` and `@`

```
Arguments = $@"Start-Process -FilePath """+arguments+$@""" -Verb RunAs"
```

Also i dont think you fully understand the `$` operator. It marks a string as an "interpolated string" which allows you to do things like below

```
int number = 100;
string score = $"Well done you scored {number}"; // Well done you scored 100
```

For example you can rewrite the `Arguments =` as below

```
Arguments = $@"Start-Process -FilePath ""{arguments}"" -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: in argument i pass the filepath how to write it?

Comment: not working the powershell open but exe not open

Comment: Your file path contains spaces inside. You should add extra quotes around the whole file path to make sure it is interpreted ans a single parameter.

Comment: you are right i change my file path it working the change path string filepath= @"C:\testing\4-1-2021\idletime\idletime\bin\Debug\idletime.exe";

Comment: how it work with the path which have spaces. string filepath=@"C:\Program Files (x86)\LalTechnologies\LT_Service\LT_Administration.exe";